# Oldest scriptural reference of Sri Hayagriva

Tags: vishnu, vaishnavism, reference-request, hayagriva

What are the oldest known scriptural evidences of Sri Hayagriva?
Does He already present inside the Vedas with some sort of Horse hymn ?

Comment: Hayagrivopanishad, begins with the Shanti Mantra(Bhadram Karnebhih ) of atharva veda , thus associated with atharva veda , is one of the 108 Upanishads.

Comment: I believe the oldest story of how Lord Vishnu became Hayagriva comes from the Shatpatha Brahmana associated with the Shukla Yajurveda

Comment: Thank You! Taking note of all possible sources